# Can anyone explain what does middleware does in this example https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, middleware

Can anyone explain what does middleware does in this example https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/
It does not support real api requests?

```
export default function clientMiddleware(client) {
return ({dispatch, getState}) => {
return next => action => {
  if (typeof action === 'function') {
    return action(dispatch, getState);
  }
  const { promise, types, ...rest } = action;
  if (!promise) {
    return next(action);
  }
  const [REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE] = types;
  next({...rest, type: REQUEST});
  const actionPromise = promise(client);
  console.log('client ');
  console.log(client);
  actionPromise.then(       
    (result) => next({...rest, result, type: SUCCESS}),
    (error) => next({...rest, error, type: FAILURE})
  ).catch((error)=> {
    console.error('MIDDLEWARE ERROR:', error);
    next({...rest, error, type: FAILURE});
  });

  return actionPromise;
};
};
}
```

Comment: Looks like promise middleware which dispatches success and fail actions for the promise

Comment: It does not wait until api call returns data

Comment: you asked this yesterday

Comment: yes not found whats wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before going to find out what the clientMiddleware does, you need to know the purposes of the following files:

`src/helpers/ApiClient.js`: a class with a set of helper methods to perform API calls

`src/redux/create.js`:
this method receives an instance of `ApiClient` as parameter `client` this is the same parameter the `clientMiddleware` gets

Now the `clietMiddleware`, the working is commented in the code

```
// The clientMiddleware basically aims to intercept actions which performs API call
// and it controls the dispatch of SUCCESS/FAILURE actions based on response
export default function clientMiddleware(client) {
    return ({dispatch, getState}) => {
        return next => action => {
            // action creator is expected to return an object but
            // if we get a function instead, lets unwrap the top layer
            // by invoking the method and see if the action creator is inside
            if (typeof action === 'function') {
              return action(dispatch, getState);
            }

            // destructure properties from action object
            const { promise, types, ...rest } = action;

            // the middleware can work only if the Object returned by
            // the action creator has a key 'promise' which is assigned
            // a function that returns promise (essentially your API call)
            if (!promise) {
              // no 'promise' key? that means this action is not an API call
              // let's pass this action to next middleware
              return next(action);
            }

            // destructures elements from types array
            // REQUEST = types[0]
            // SUCCESS = types[1]
            // FAILURE = types[2]
            const [REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE] = types;

            // Call next middleware with action.type = REQUEST
            // this will eventually get dipatched and the REQUEST reducer will get executed
            // Invokes a reducer just before the API call
            // a chance to set flags like 'loading': { ...state, loading: true }
            next({ ...rest, type: REQUEST });

            // as I said before 'promise' is a function we got by destructuring 'actions'
            // and that function receives instance of ApiClient as parameter
            // thus in turn a promise is returned and we are storing that to a variable here
            const actionPromise = promise(client);

            // as the name says, 'actionPromise'' is a JavaScipt promise, a 'then'able one.
            actionPromise.then(
                // on succesfull completion of the API call dispatch the SUCCESS action with result
                // from API response, any additional parameters required by the reducer goes in ...rest
                (result) => next({ ...rest, result, type: SUCCESS }),

                // similar to the success case, we dipatch the FAILURE action with error when API fails
                (error) => next({ ...rest, error, type: FAILURE })
            ).catch((error)=> {
                next({ ...rest, error, type: FAILURE });
            });

            return actionPromise;
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: great explanation. does this middleware can handle async call on server?

Comment: of course, if you have server side rendering, the middleware works on your server too.

Comment: One more thing I want to know is. what is mean by return {
  types: [LOAD, LOAD_SUCCESS, LOAD_FAIL],
  promise: (client) => client.get('http://testapi.com')
 }; code in modules

Comment: `[REQUEST, SUCCESS, FAILURE] = [LOAD, LOAD_SUCCESS, LOAD_FAIL]`, and  function assigned to `promise` key is our `actionPromise` in middleware.

Comment: axios.get('http://test.com/ajax/gettestdata').then(function(res){
  var data = res.data;
  return {
   types: [LOAD, LOAD_SUCCESS, LOAD_FAIL],
   promise: (client) => function Promise((resolve) => {
   resolve({
      message: 'This came from the api server',
      time: 12131323
    })}
  });
 }); this does not work. I am really new to react. Sorry can you explain why this code does not work?

Comment: api return values, I just have put sample domain there

Comment: I am afraid it is really hard to read code from comments, and I think since this is another part of the App, how about a separate question with relevant code?

Comment: I added in original question Edit 1: If I do like this with axios call does not work

Comment: I am not seeing your edit in the original question. But try to write a separate Stack Overflow question as this is a different issue. You will get more people to answer it, I look into that too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40897900/how-to-make-async-call-with-redux-middleware-in-this-example-https-github-com